# Equivalence of semantic and syntactic criteria for valid definitions

Tags: logic, definition, model-theory

This [SEP](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/definitions/) article on definitions claims that the semantic and syntactic criteria it states for a valid definition are not equivalent. If we're working in standard first-order logic, I don't see how this could be. Could you help?

I've copied the relevant section below, with the claim highlighted:

[image]

Here's an attempted proof for the conservativeness criterion. Let $\Gamma \subseteq L$ be
the theory under consideration, and $\Delta \subseteq L^+$ contain our definitions. Then:

1. For all $\phi$ in $L$, if $\Gamma \cup \Delta \vdash \phi$ then $\Gamma \vdash \phi$
   (Premise).
2. Assume for an arbitrary $\phi$ in $L$ that $\Gamma \cup \Delta \models \phi$.
3. Then, by strong completeness, $\Gamma \cup \Delta \vdash \phi$.
4. From 1 and 3, $\Gamma \vdash \phi$.
5. Then, by strong soundness, $\Gamma \models \phi$.
6. From 2-5, if $\Gamma \cup \Delta \models \phi$ then $\Gamma \models \phi$.
7. Thus, for all $\phi$ in $L$, if $\Gamma \cup \Delta \models \phi$ then $\Gamma \models
      \phi$.

The other direction is analogously proven to establish equivalence.

Similarly, a proof for the eliminability criterion can be generated:

1. For all $\phi$ in $L^+$, there exists $\psi \in L$ such that $\Gamma \cup \Delta
      \vdash \phi \leftrightarrow \psi$ (Premise).
2. Assume for an arbitrary $\phi$ in $L^+$ that some $\psi^* \in L$ is such that $\Gamma \cup \Delta
      \vdash \phi \leftrightarrow \psi^*$.
3. Then, by string soundness, we have $\Gamma \cup \Delta \models \phi \leftrightarrow \psi^*$.
4. Thus, for all $\phi$ in $L$ there exists $\psi \in L$ such that $\Gamma \cup \Delta
      \models \phi \leftrightarrow \psi$.

The other direction is analogously proven to establish equivalence.

Comment: Um I wrote up something for your question about Peano systems, but you deleted it before I could post my answer... It's actually an interesting and difficult question, so I'd be disappointed if you kept it deleted.

Comment: @user21820 Im opening it again. Very sorry.

Comment: @user21820 It's open again.

Comment: No need to be sorry for deleting a question that had no answers. It's just that the question is deceptively simple, but actually not. I've posted my answer, but if you feel it's not enough to address your question (I'm sort of guessing what your underlying enquiry entails) let me know in the comments over there!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure it out but my best guess is that the difference is because the author assumes definitions are rules of inference, so adding them changes the deduction system. I instead assume they are non-logical axioms (not part of the deduction system), and adding them doesn't change the deduction system.